# SQL table1 row_id not show table2 row_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is my SQL query

```
select c.course_id,c.course_title,c.course_credits,c.course_status from       
 course c,(select course_id from completed_course 
 where student_id='1229CSE00241') as a
 where c.course_id!=a.course_id
```

But it show all row of a courses also but I want only courses of c which
 doesn't in courses of a.

Comment: Did you try with the query I answered?

Comment: i don't  understand where is your answer . i m new in here

Comment: `select c.course_id,c.course_title,c.course_credits,c.course_status ,IFNULL(cc.student_id,0) as complete_course from course c left join completed_course cc on c.course_id=cc.course_id and cc.student_id='1229CSE00241' having complete_course=0`

Comment: Did you try this query , Does n't It work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
c.course_id,
c.course_title,
c.course_credits,
c.course_status 
from course c 
where 
c.course_id NOT IN (select course_id from completed_course where student_id='1229CSE00241');
```

Comment: wow thanks its work nicely..
thanks also stack-overflow  its help me when i face any problem...

Comment: please tell me why my previous query is not working. i try many way but it not working but when i ask question in stackoverflow it done quickly...

Comment: because in my example it gets the list course_id-s as an argument that not will be in result of parent query.
but in Your example it gets 2 results and runs every row and compares them maybe in 1-st row of 1-st query it has row c.course_id = 5 and in Your second query it has row a.course_id = 5 then it will skip the row and when for example c.course_id=5 and a.course_id=4 occurs it joins these results and then returns certain values
if You want to see the difference make (select c.course_id,c.course_title,c.course_credits,c.course_status, a.course_id from) in Your 1-st query.

Comment: short - in Your query it joins results by fields that not equal

Comment: please help me for this program 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433144/dont-stop-same-data-insert-in-php-mysql-base-on-same-id

Comment: suppose i want to add a course in completed course list.. when i add cse101 subject it store with id and course details but when i click back menu in add completed course page it show same cse101 cause i dont refresh page but without refresh page same cse101 course in my database so there is 2 row cse101 course thats a big problem for me cause database store same data .
completed_course table

student_id      course_id
00241              CSE101
00241              CSE101

but i want same data for same student is not entry my table ..
is there is any way to solve my problem??

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.course_id,
c.course_title,
c.course_credits,
c.course_status 
from course c where c.course_id not in 
(select course_id from completed_course where student_id='1229CSE00241')
```